# Weird error when bringing up docker image for postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker stack using multiple images. One of them being docker image of postgres. Now, I have been working on this for couple of months but since yesterday my postgres image just started failing and when I debugged the service, I found following errors in the log:

```
LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
iaap_manager-db.1.5ajswuqhk7se@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:12.513 UTC [18] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
iaap_manager-db.1.6g83gkc55on3@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:21.877 UTC [19] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1670AE0: wanted 24, got 0
iaap_manager-db.1.94tmkm7nnaxr@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:30.009 UTC [19] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1670AE0: wanted 24, got 0
iaap_manager-db.1.wwpvypju8wdr@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:04.113 UTC [19] LOG:  invalid resource manager ID in secondary checkpoint record
iaap_manager-db.1.6g83gkc55on3@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:21.877 UTC [19] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
iaap_manager-db.1.5ajswuqhk7se@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:12.513 UTC [18] LOG:  invalid resource manager ID in secondary checkpoint record
iaap_manager-db.1.5ajswuqhk7se@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:12.513 UTC [18] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
iaap_manager-db.1.5ajswuqhk7se@linuxkit-025000000001    | 2018-06-12 18:16:12.514 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 18) was terminated by signal 6
```

I have no idea what does it even mean. Any ideas?

Comment: Smells like a disk issue. Are you out of space? Check your hardware imo.

Comment: @JacobH: I have plenty of space on my local machine. However, I think the issue was related to docker volume attached to postgres image. As soon as I removed the volume and restarted the container, the problem got resolved. Thanks for your help